# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Use

rails 4.0.2  and 
activeadmin 1.0

Models:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
translates :url, :alt_tag, :h1, :content, :name, :nav_content, :meta_desc, :meta_title

has_many :tag_translations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_translations, allow_destroy: true

end

class class TagTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :tag
  validates_uniqueness_of :locale, :scope => :tag_id
end
```

activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tag do



      def permitted_params
          params.permit tag: [:name, :active_general, :active_general_breakfasts, :active_general_apartments, 
                    :active_article, :country_id, :region_id, :active_country_houses, :active_country_appartments,
                    :active_country, :meta_desc, :meta_title, :active_house, :active_apartment, :tag_list, 
                    :nav_content, :alt_tag, :h1, :content, :name, tag_translations_attributes: [:id, :tag_id, :locale, 
                     :alt_tag, :h1, :content, :name, :nav_content, :meta_desc, :meta_title, :_destroy, :_create, :_update,:_update]]
      end  

end
```

i get this error message in the logfile. What am i doing wrong here?

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Tag: country_id, region_id, active_house, active_apartment, active_general, active_general_apartments, active_general_breakfasts, active_article, name, h1, content, alt_tag, nav_content, url, meta_desc, meta_title

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Tag::Translation: locale
```

thanks..remco

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tag do

  permit_params :name, :active_general, :active_general_breakfasts, :active_general_apartments, 
                :active_article, :country_id, :region_id, :active_country_houses, :active_country_appartments,
                :active_country, :meta_desc, :meta_title, :active_house, :active_apartment, :tag_list, 
                :nav_content, :alt_tag, :h1, :content, :name, tag_translations_attributes: [:id, :tag_id, :locale, 
                 :alt_tag, :h1, :content, :name, :nav_content, :meta_desc, :meta_title, :_destroy, :_create, :_update,:_update]

end
```